# Rigid body particle system?

Tags: particles

I'm gonna try to make this as clear as possible. I have an animated conveyor belt in Blender and there's going to be a machine right on top of it that's just going to drop some cubes onto the conveyor belt.

I made the conveyor belt a passive rigid body and the cubes that were going to drop from the machine would be an active rigid body. Here's the problem, I want the cubes to continuously spawn from the machine one by one and drop right onto the conveyor belt. I could duplicate a lot of rigid body cubes but I don't want them to drop all at once, nor do I want to manually animate the passive to active rigid body on more than a hundred cubes.

I tried to do a workaround by using a particle system with the conveyor belt with collision physics, and it did work for the most part, but half of the cube goes through the conveyor belt, and the particles don't collide with each other at all.

I am aware there is an addon called Molecular or something, but I think it was only compatible for Blender 2.77.

Comment: Molecular works in 2.80. There was a port not too long ago. As far as I know it's the only way to have particles collide with each other.

Comment: Found the link to the BA thread:
https://blenderartists.org/t/addon-moleculars-physics/521682/250

Comment: You can achieve this with the help of animation nodes and particles here is a similar tutorial link: youtube.com/watch?v=G1ysjPeLKSQ